# C# Jagged Array vs Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary

What would the memory/speed be like for the current three scenarios?
I haven’t seen much talk about using dictionaries in this way.

But surely if dictionaries have super fast lookup speed, wouldn’t either of the dictionary implementations be more ideal for scenarios where there’s a lot more lookup/accessing than adding?

```cs
var array = new string[100][200][100];

for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++)
for (var y = 0; y < 200; y++)
for (var z = 0; z < 300; z++)
    array[x][y][z] = “Done”;

for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++)
for (var y = 0; y < 200; y++)
for (var z = 0; z < 300; z++)
    Console.Write(array[x][y][z]);
```

vs

```cs
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>>();

for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++)
for (var y = 0; y < 200; y++)
for (var z = 0; z < 300; z++)
    dictionary[x][y][z] = “Done”;

for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++)
for (var y = 0; y < 200; y++)
for (var z = 0; z < 300; z++)
    Console.Write(dictionary[x][y][z]);
```

vs

```cs
struct Vector3
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;
}
 
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Vector3, string>();

var vector = new Vector3();
for (vector.X < 100; vector.X++)
for (vector.Y < 200; vector.Y++)
for (vector.Z < 300; vector.Z++)
    dictionary[vector] = “Done”;

for (vector.X < 100; vector.X++)
for (vector.Y < 200; vector.Y++)
for (vector.Z < 300; vector.Z++)
    Console.Write(dictionary[vector]);
```

Comment: Could you please post real, runable code?

Comment: Why ask us? You can benchmark these 3,and get a sense of accomplishment and enjoyment out of the process. Also note, you should be benchmarking your actual code

Comment: Anyway as a rule of thumb, `Dictionary` are good for lookups to reduce scanning a collection. however you are scanning in all examples, dictionary will be slower

Comment: You need to learn about [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). And never include smart quotes in your code, they're the devil. Use regular double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary` lookup cannot outperform an array lookup by index. Both are O(1) operations, with the `Dictionary` introducing hashcode-related overhead, while also having a larger memory footprint. You could consider using a `Dictionary` only in case you had sparse data in a huge 3D array. For example if only one of every 1,000 cells were actually populated. In that case using dictionaries would still have worse performance, but at least your program would consume less memory.